# How can I filter when selecting the necessary options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I work with anisotropic filtering. But now filtering occurs immediately after clicking on the button. Code: enter code herehttps://codepen.io/HutsonR/pen/OJMmKNL

I need the user to be able to select all the necessary settings(option) in select and after clicking the "Search" button, the necessary cards selected by the filter are displayed. How to configure the isotope script so that you do not need to click on the buttons from the isotope, but you need to select the desired option and after clicking on the "Search" button, the desired cards will be selected?
If you know another convenient plugin for the settings I need(by selecting the option and clicking on the button), you can recommend it) thank you in advance for your help! :) And sorry for my English. I'm from Russia :)

Comment: I had trouble looking through all the code to find where your problem is. (The snippet didn't help much since it contains no script.) Maybe clarifying what should happen when user clicks search could help get you better responses?

Comment: Changed the text of the question, made it more convenient with the code